# Using class members in ActionListener

Tags: java, swing

I am having issue using a timer. I create a ship that shoots upwards at random times (the ship is moving from left to right.)

The point is actually that it will shoot from random places on the X axis.

From my search I understood that I have to use `ActionListener` inside my `Ship` class and inside it I am supposed to create the shot. My problem is the following:

How can I use the `Ship` class members inside the `actionPerformed function? So that I will know the location of the ship at the time and create the shot location accordingly.

Comment: Sounds like you should make it final to allow the access from the listener. Your IDE like eclipse should tell you that.

Comment: Yes, but how can I make it final if the values of the members change all the time? The ship is moving and thus the members of the location of the ship change all the time

Comment: There are several ways. You could wrap the position in an own class. That can be final but it's values are mutable.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `ActionListener` a non-static inner class. Such classes have access to members of the outer class:

```
public class Ship {
    private int location;

    public Ship() {
        <gui>.addActionListener(new Listener());
    }

    private class Listener implements ActionListener {
         void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             // here we can access location and other Ship members
         }
    }
}
```

If you are using Java8 you can drop the action listener class and use a method handle to be notified when an action event occurs:

```
public class Ship {
    private int location;


    public Ship() {
        <gui>.addActionListener(this::onAction);
    }

    private void onAction(ActionEvent e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, but can you please explain to me the part of the <gui>? and why is this the solution?..

Comment: the <gui> is just a placeholder for your gui control(s) on which register the actionlistener.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the following:

- Declare the local variables you need to access inside the `actionListener` as `final`.
- Declare the variables you need to access inside the `actionListener` as class members.

Good Luck.